# Newline after a specified number of spaces

Tags: php, html

I want to know how to count to the second space then return to the newline with php , for example :

the text: "How are you?" 
becomes

"how are 
you?"

how can I do that with php?

thank you

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Do you want a line break before and after the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function addNlToText($text) {
    $words = explode(' ', $text);
   $out = '';
   foreach ($words as $key => $value) {
       $out .= $value;
       if ($key % 2 === 0) {
           $out .= "\n";
       } else {
           $out .= ' ';
       }
   }
   return trim($out);
}
```

That's dirty, but it does what you ask...

```
$text = 'Hello, how are you?';
addNlToText($text); // "Hello, how\nare you?"
$text = 'Hello';
addNlToText($text); // "Hello"
$text = 'Hello what is going on?';
addNlToText($text); // "Hello what\nis going\non?"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function that uses strpos to return the position of the Nth specified character.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#96576

Find that position, then do a substr_replace to put a \n in that spot.

Answer (score 4):

```
print preg_replace('/((:?\S+\s){2})/i', "\$1\r\n",  "How are you?" );
```

Comment: I'm reading the PHP manual to understand the regexp. Is this a sub pattern? In such case is the exact syntax '/((?: ...' ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php

Comment: it is non-capturing group (?: ) inside of capturing group. ((:?\S+\s){2}) is equivalent to (\S+\s\S+\s)

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you are not after something like the wordwrap function?

http://www.php.net/wordwrap

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$mystring = 'How are you?';
$findme   = ' ';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme, $pos+1);
$mystring = substr_replace($mystring, '<br>', $pos, 0);
echo $mystring;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using javascript, Is it ok using javascript?

Comment: You can use a function that counts the spaces in a string, than when it finds the second space it will be replaced with a new line. I think you can continue with this idea, If you need the full code just tell me I'll start writing.. :)